# XSLT copy from external document

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In XSLT 2.0 I am transforming a `tei-xml` document into HTML. In that transformationI need content from another document:  I want to copy/transform a small set of nodes from the second document into the HTML output.

While processing the principal `tei` document I get the id and assign it to a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="licenseid" select="./replace(@corresp,'#','')"/>
```

Then I go out to the other document and fetch the node using the variable, with the returned node assigned to a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="licenseloc" select="doc(concat($somepath,'includes_sourcedesc.xml'))//tei:list[@type='copyright_type']/tei:item[@xml:id=$licenseid]"/>
```

This node I obtain looks like this:

```
<list type="copyright_type">
  <item xml:id="copyright-cc-by-nc-sa-4.0">
     <desc xml:lang="en">This work is made by available the author under the 
     <ref target="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 
        4.0 International License</ref>.</desc>
  </item>
</list>
```

And I want to transform it (from `desc`) to this:

```
<span>This work is made by available by the author under the 
     <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 
        4.0 International License</a>.</span>
```

If this were in my 'current' `tei` document I would handle it through templates, but I'm unsure how to copy and transform the nested layers from within a different 'current' document.

Comment: You can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$licenseloc"/>` (if needed with a `mode="some-mode"`) and then write templates as usual for the element(s).

Comment: @MartinHonnen well now that you say it, it's obvious. I was locked into the idea that templates must concern the 'current file' instead of thinking with 'nodes'. Thanks very much.